# Fantasy novel about 3-5 kids who have unique powers and live in a world where everyone belongs to a single race

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic, psychic

The novel is about a group of 3-5 children who have unique powers. One of them is super in tune with nature and can heal things. Another has psychic abilities. Something interesting I remember is everyone being one race, and I'm pretty sure it was a machine that made it that way. Oriental eyes is the only thing I remember about how the race was described. There was a psychic villain who seemed to be chasing the kids. They took shelter in a cave-type thing where they met someone who teaches them to control their powers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: i want to say it was 4-5 years ago when i read it, and i remember nothing about the publish date and cover. I think the antagonist was always wearing shades though.